# Access to component method in reactjs not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access a child method from the parent component. This is how the child code looks like

```
class child extends Component {

someMethod(v) {
// do something
}

render(){
return(
...
)
}
}
```

And this is the parent code

```
class Parent extends Component {
hoverOn(){
this._Child.someMethod(10);  // _Child is undefined here
}

render(){
return(
<div onMouseOver={this.hoverOn.bind(this)}>
<OtherChild ....>
<Child  ref={(Child) => { this._Child = Child; }} />
</div>
)
}
}
```

On hoverOn() I get an error telling me that _Child is undefined. How can I call someMethod() from the Parent Class?

Comment: hmm. weird. Your code snippet seems correct.

Comment: Two things, your child component class names is `child` whereas it should be `Child`, other thing is that since you have onMouseOver event which may get triggered before the component is mounted and hence you can get an error so add a conditional check like `this._Child && this._Child.someMethod(10);`

Answer (score 0):

try adding refs

```
class Parent extends Component {
hoverOn(){
    this.refs._Child.someMethod(10);
}}
```

Comment: The OP has added a ref  using the callback method which is what is recommended in the docs

Comment: OP has used a better method than what you've suggested.

Comment: Oh sorry guys . I didnt see that he used a callback method